# How can I configure the width of vertical WindowsXP taskbar to stop it expanding?

Tags: windows, taskbar

I prefer to place my Windows taskbar vertically on the right, but I want it to be one icon wide not two, that way if I have multiple copies of the same app running I can hover of the apps icon for it to display the titles of its windows and select the one I want.

When I have a lot of apps showing the icons are displayed in two columns, but I want them displayed in one column so multiple copies of the same app are displayed with one icon.

Is there some registry setting for setting the width of the task bar when displayed vertically, something just above the size of the icons.?

This approach works okay when the taskbar is horizontal but not when it is vertical. Is there some way I can fix this?

Comment: Maybe you can get it the way you want and then lock it.

Comment: @martineau post it as the answer

Comment: the default width of the taskbar is too wide to start with. I need it to be half its width such as when it's horizontal.